# Update a JSON File value depending on the key name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I got a following ejs form snippet: What this does is show the data from the json file.

```
<form method="post" action="/save" id="form_Update">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table width="900px;" height="80px;">
         <% for(var i=0; i < myKeyList.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px"><b><%= myKeyList[i] %> :: </b></td>
                <td style="height: 10px" ></td>
                <td>
                  <b><input type="text" name="<%=myKeyList[i]%>" id="jsonValue" class="form-control" value="<%= mykeyValues[i]%>" style="width: 400px"></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want do to is that when I click the save button, I want to update the json file key name based on the new value i will input on the texbox. bear in mind that the json file got another  data like this:

```
{
    "data1":[{
      "error": "'I am an error!'",
      "url": "'localhost'"
    }],
    "data2": [{
      "vm": "value"
   }],
    "data3": [{
      "ignore": "'ignoreme'"
   }]
}
```

For example i want to update the value of the "vm" key name to value1, so it should be "vm": "value1" but still having the other data.

I tried get doing this which updates the value:

```
fs.writeFile('./data1.json', JSON.stringify(newKeyValueHere, null, 4));
```

But this is just creating a new file and not updating the file i got.

Comment: Well, first you have to read the file into a js object. Then you amend the `$data.data2[0].vm` to the new value, then you have to convert the js object back to a JSON String and re-write the file

Comment: If you have done anything like this then show us all your code and not just one line